# importance of correlation between data for a PROC CLUSTER

Tags: correlation, clustering, sas, hierarchical-clustering, eigenvalues

i'm working on a clustering analysis on SAS.

I need to improve an actual code :

```
PROC CLUSTER METHOD=WARD DATA= Distance_matrix
NOEIGEN
CCC
PSEUDO
PRINT = 50
OUTTREE= Tree; 
id item1;
```

This is doing a **Hierarchical clustering** using the ward distance. The data are a distance matrix on product x product.

And i was wondering about the ***NOEIGEN*** argument of this method. SAS say :

> **NOEIGEN:** suppresses computation of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix and
>   substitutes the variances of the variables for the eigenvalues when
>   computing the cubic clustering criterion. The NOEIGEN option saves
>   time if the number of variables is large, but it should be used only
>   if the variables are nearly uncorrelated. If you specify the NOEIGEN
>   option and the variables are highly correlated, the cubic clustering
>   criterion might be very liberal. The NOEIGEN option applies only to
>   coordinate data.

But, automatically there is some correlation in the data no? Otherwise we wouldn't be able to cluster them in categories...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are a large number of variables, a whole lot of small correlations can lead to useful clusters. Of course, defining what exactly "large" and "small" and "useful" mean would need a lot of Monte Carlo work.

Note, however, the last sentence of the highlighted text: NOEIGEN only works on coordinate data and you have a distance matrix.